# SendCode and REPL not working

Tags: r, sublimetext3

So I am new in sublimetext and I work on R. I manage to install package control, SendText, SendCode, R-box and REPL.
When I lunch REPL R its work, but when I create a new window for R script and configure it:

1. cmd+shift+P Set Syntax: R Extended
2. cmd+shift+P SendText+: Choose Program

The code cannot be send it to the REPL R consol. I try several solution found in the web but nothing is working. I also try to link SendCode with my Rstudio but is not working nether.

My REPL user setting is the following:

```
{
 "default_extend_env": {"PATH": "{PATH};C:\\Program Files\\R\\R- 
 3.4.3\\bin\\x64"},
 "show_transferred_text": true
}
```

My SendCode user setting is the following:

```
{
 "prog": "sublimerepl",
 "r":
 {
   "prog": "sublimerepl"
 }
}
```

My R-boxuser setting is the following:

```
{
 // path to Rgui.exe
 "R64": "C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-3.4.3\\bin\\x64"
}
```

Thanks for your help